# Mocking an environment in Angular with Jasmine

Tags: javascript, angular, unit-testing, mocking, spy

I'm still learning how to write tests for angular using Karma/Jasmine. I want to return false for the environment's isDebugMode. It works obviously when I change the code for it but how do I write a test for that? I have set up some tests trying figure out how to mock the environment. But none seem to work the way I think it does. I was wondering if someone could explain why these are returning the values they do.

```
import { TestBed, inject } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { LoggerService } from './logger.service';
import { environment } from '../environments/environment';
import { mockEnvironment} from '../environments/environment.mock';

describe('Test', () => {

  beforeEach(() => {

    spyOn(console, 'error');
    spyOn(console, 'warn');

    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      providers: [ LoggerService ]
    });


  });

  it('should be created',
    inject([LoggerService],
      (service: LoggerService) => {
        expect(service).toBeTruthy();
      }));

  it('should always work', function() {
    expect(true).toBe(true);
  });

  it('is the mocked environment returning false', function() {
    spyOn(mockEnvironment, 'isDebugMode');
    expect(mockEnvironment.isDebugMode).toEqual(false);
  });

  it('is the environment returning true', function() {
    spyOn(environment, 'isDebugMode');
    expect(environment.isDebugMode).toEqual(true);
  });

  it('enclosing in function makes everything true, why?',
    function () {
    spyOn(environment, 'isDebugMode').and.returnValue(false);
    inject([LoggerService],
      (service: LoggerService) => {
        const type = 'warn';
        const message = 'This message';
        service.log(type, message);

        expect(console.warn).not.toHaveBeenCalled(); // this does not seem to matter
      });
     }
  );
  it('enclosing in function makes everything true, why?',
    function () {
      spyOn(environment, 'isDebugMode').and.returnValue(false);
      inject([LoggerService],
        (service: LoggerService) => {
          const type = 'warn';
          const message = 'This message';
          service.log(type, message);

          expect(console.warn).toHaveBeenCalled(); // this does not seem to matter
        });
    }
  );
  it('should show up if isDebugMode is true',
    inject([LoggerService],
      (service: LoggerService) => {
        const type = 'warn';
        const message = 'This message';

        service.log(type, message);
        expect(console.warn).toHaveBeenCalled(); // this works
      })
  );
  it('should not show up if isDebugMode is false using spy with return value',
      inject([LoggerService],
        (service: LoggerService) => {
          const type = 'warn';
          const message = 'This message';
          spyOn(environment, 'isDebugMode').and.returnValue(false);

          service.log(type, message);
          expect(console.warn).not.toHaveBeenCalled(); // this is does not work
        })
  );
  it('should not show up if isDebugMode is false using spy with callfake',
    inject([LoggerService],
      (service: LoggerService) => {
        const type = 'warn';
        const message = 'This message';
        spyOn(environment, 'isDebugMode').and.callFake(mockEnvironment.isDebugMode); // boolean is not a function

        service.log(type, message);
        expect(console.warn).not.toHaveBeenCalled(); // this is does not work
      })
  );
  it('should not show up if isDebugMode is false using spy with stub',
    inject([LoggerService],
      (service: LoggerService) => {
        const type = 'warn';
        const message = 'This message';
        spyOn(environment, 'isDebugMode').and.stub();

        service.log(type, message);
        expect(console.warn).not.toHaveBeenCalled(); // this is does not work
      })
  );


});
```

These are the files I'm trying to test: 
logger.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { environment } from '../environments/environment';

const isDebugMode = environment.isDebugMode;

@Injectable()
export class LoggerService {

  log(type: string, message?: any): void {
    if (type === 'info' || type === 'warn' || type === 'debug' || type === 'error' || type === 'log') {
      const logFn: Function = (console)[type];
      if (isDebugMode) {
        logFn.apply(console, [message]);
      }
    } else {
      console.error('Logger type incorrect');
    }
  }
}
```

With the environment.ts

```
export const environment = {
  production: false,
  hmr: false,
  isDebugMode: true
};
```

and environment.mock.ts

```
export const MockEnvironment = {
  production: false,
  hmr: false,
  isDebugMode: false
};
```

Test

- should be created - pass
- should always work - pass
- is the mocked environment returning false - fail
- is the environment returning true - fail
- enclosing in function makes everything true, why? - pass
- enclosing in function makes everything true, why? - pass
- should show up if isDebugMode is true - pass
- should not show up if isDebugMode is false using spy with return value - fail
- should not show up if isDebugMode is false using spy with callfake - fail
- should not show up if isDebugMode is false using spy with stub - fail

Comment: Could you post the code for environment.ts?  Also, the code might be a little nicer if you used an enum or a type union over some strings in place of `type === 'info' || type === 'warn' || type === 'debug' || type === 'error' || type === 'log'`.